# JQuery hide Checkbox depending on dropdown value

Tags: jquery

I would like to use JQuery to change the display of checkboxes depending on the value of a selected div.  Specifically, I would like to hide the "Neukölln" and "Mitte" checkboxes if 'Berlin' is selected in the facetwp-facet-city dropdown. I know this is possible using JQuery, but unfortunately my skills aren't quite at that level (yet). Any help would be much appreciated! In the screenshot, I've highlighted the 'Berlin' value and the `Mitte` checkbox.

The screenshot url is: https://www.wgeil.de/listings/?fwp_city=berlin
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What solutions have you tried? Show us your code, and someone can probably help debug it for you.

Comment: I've tried this code (courtesy of shi), but it is not working. Any idea why not? 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.facetwp-dropdown').on('change', function(e) {
    if ($(this).val() == 'berlin')
      $('.facetwp-checkbox').each(function(i, v) {
        if ($(this).data("value") == 'mitte') {
          $(this).hide();
        }
        if ($(this).data("value") == 'neukolln') {
          $(this).hide();
        }
      })
  })
});

Comment: Post actual code instead of screenshot or make a fiddle. It will be easier for us to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.facetwp-dropdown').on('change', function(e) {
    if ($(this).val() == 'berlin')
      $('.facetwp-checkbox').each(function(i, v) {
        if ($(this).data("value") == 'mitte') {
          $(this).hide();
        }
        if ($(this).data("value") == 'neukolln') {
          $(this).hide();
        }
      })
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot!

Comment: Did you included jQuery in your HTML? Can you create a fiddle? It will be easier to find out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Taking some inspiration shi's code, here is a possible solution. To help out going forward, if something doesn't work you may want to see if it drops errors in the console (and then try and debug them), or potentially add some `console.log(/* some variable */);` statements to list what is being returned by some of the selectors, which might allow you to figure out where things are failing (or at least point you at a specific question to ask).

```
// formatting for readability.
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Should trigger callback function on change in dropdown.
  $('.facetwp-dropdown').on('change', function(e) {

    // Should set the value of the selected dropdown option.
    let selectedOption = $(this).find(':selected').prop('value');

    // Conditional if option equals berlin.
    if (selectedOption == 'berlin') {
      // Grab all checkboxes using their parent div.
      let checkboxes = $('.facet-wrapper').children();

      // Use jQuery.each method to iterate over the child elements.
      $.each(checkboxes, function(index, value) {
        // Set value of the data attribute.
        let attribute = $(value).attr('data-value');

        // Check data attribute value against either option.
        if (attribute == 'neukolln' || attribute == 'mitte') {
          // Hide div if conditional evaluates true.
          $(value).hide();
        }
      });
    }    
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out!

Comment: your first issue is that you set `selectedOption` equal to your selector, but then try and test against `selectOption` in your conditionals :) (did that in my code example, sorry for the typo). Once you fix that hiding something in jquery is as easy as `$('/*your selector*/').hide();`